# DAX - IsSubTotal - Doesn't seem to be working correctly?

Tags: dax

I have the following DAX query created in DAX Studio. I guess I don't have a good understanding how ISSUBTOTAL is supposed to work. For example:

The first row shows true for all three ISSUBTOTAL statements. This is a grand total, not a year, month or day total.

The second row shows False for Is Year Total yet I would expect a True here since it is a yearly total. I don't know why Is Month Total and Is Day Total show true.

The last row shows False for Is Day Total yet I would expect True since this is a daily total.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A total in DAX perspective is one where there is no context contributed by the column in context. Your [Is Year Total] indicates `TRUE` when no year is in context (i.e. total across all years) and `FALSE` when a year is in context (i.e. measure is filtered by a year). So for your second row where we have the following:

```
[Is Year Total] = FALSE
[Is Month Total] = TRUE
[Is Day Total] = TRUE
```

This indicates that there is a year in context (2008), but there is no month or day in context. So a measure would be evaluated with a filter context of `[Year]=2008`.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to make sense.Frankly I think it would have been more useful to have, for example, [Is Month Total] = True mean, "This represents the subtotal for the month".

Comment: I get your point. DAX is a language with very different paradigms than most other languages. Almost all evaluation is based around an execution context. So totaling is done by removing context (e.g. removing month and day context leaves only year context, thus totaling across months and days). It will be helpful to read the following articles to understand more about context in DAX: 1) https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2449191 2) https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/ 3) https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/

Answer (score 0):

Subtotal:
the total of one set of a larger group of figures to be added.

I would interprete this for the the second row. You are looking at the Year level, at a single Value of the whole column, so it is not a subtotal of Year.